# Problema con variable de iteracion en bucle for de Python

Tags: python, variables, bucle-for

chicos.
Tengo el siguiente problema: estoy tratando de definir esta función para que esta me permita tomar un archivo de texto cargado previamente y contar cuántas líneas de texto contiene. La cuestión es que Visual Studio Code me muestra algo como "unused variable 'line'" en la sección de "Problemas". Este es el fragmento de código:

```
#Funcion numero de lineas:
def totalines(archivo):
    for line in archivo:
        cantidadLineas = cantidadLineas + 1
        print("Cantidad de lineas totales: ", cantidadLineas)
```

Cuando intento utilizar esta función, el intérprete se salta todo el código y termina en una excepción que he colocado para manejar errores. ¿Qué me está faltando aquí?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto:

> Unused variable `line`

no es un error es un aviso del linter (pylint por ejemplo) porque la variable `line` del `for` no se usa en ningún momento. Según las convenciones, cuando tenemos una variable que no es usada nunca se nombra mediante un simple subrayado (`_`)

En vez de:

```
for line in archivo:
```

simplemente:

```
 for _ in archivo:
```

Dos apuntes:

- Ten en cuenta que un archivo (descriptor) se comporta exactamente como un iterador, es decir, si has iterado sobre archivo antes de llamar a `totalines`, esta empezará a iterar desde dónde se quedó el cursor, no desde el inicio del fichero, por lo que el numero de filas contadas será menor. Es recomendable colocar el cursor al inicio del fichero y luego restaurarlo a su posición original.
- No inicializas la variable `cantidadlineas` en la función ni tampoco la declaras como global, eso terminará con una verdadera excepción:

  > UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cantidadlines' referenced before assignment

El código debería ser en todo caso:

```
def totalines(archivo):
    cur_pos = archivo.tell()
    archivo.seek(0)
    cantidad_lineas = 0
    for _ in archivo:
        cantidad_lineas += 1
    archivo.seek(cur_pos)
    print("Cantidad de lineas totales: ", cantidad_lineas)
```

Una forma muy simple de contar las lineas de un fichero sin cargar el archivo al completo simultáneamente en memoria (lo cual no debemos hacer nunca si no es necesario) es usar simplemente una expresión generadora con un `for` in que genere 1 por cada fila  y aplicar  `sum`  a la expresión:

```
def totalines(archivo):
    cur_pos = archivo.tell()
    archivo.seek(0)
    lineas = sum(1 for _ in f)
    archivo.seek(cur_pos)
    return lineas
```

O pasando la ruta y abriendo el archivo:

```
def totalines(ruta_archivo):
    with open(ruta_archivo) as f:
        return sum(1 for _ in f)
```

luego simplemente llámala:

> ```
> print("Cantidad de lineas totales: ", totalines("mi_archivo.txt"))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `len(archivo.readlines())` para contar las líneas del archivo, no necesitas de un bucle..

El método `readlines()` va a leer todas las líneas del archivo y el método `len()` la cantidad de líneas

Prueba algo así:

```
#Funcion numero de lineas:
def totalines(archivo):
   cantidadLineas = len(archivo.readlines())   #  Aquí la modificación
   print("Cantidad de lineas totales: ", cantidadLineas)
```